# Merge small files from S3 to create a 10 Mb file

Tags: amazon-s3, mapreduce, amazon-emr, mrjob

I am new to map reduce. I have a s3 bucket that gets 3000 files every minute. I am trying to use Map reduce to merge these files to make a file between size 10 -100 MB. The python code will use Mrjob and will run on aws EMR. Mrjob's documentation say, mapper_raw can be used to pass entire files to the mapper.

class MRCrawler(MRJob):

```
def mapper_raw(self, wet_path, wet_uri):
    from warcio.archiveiterator import ArchiveIterator

    with open(wet_path, 'rb') as f:
        for record in ArchiveIterator(f):
            ...
```

Is there a way to limit it to only read 5000 files in one run and delete those files after the reducer saves the results to S3 so that the same files are not picked in the next run.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

1. configure SQS on the S3 bucket
2. have lambda which gets triggered by cron; which reads the events from the SQS and copies the relevant files into a staging folder -- you can configure this lambda to read only 5000 messages at a given time.
3. do all your processing on top of staging folder and once you're done with your Spark job in emr, clean the staging folder